# HTML5 canvas stroke() thick and fuzzy

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, stroke

I'm trying to allow the user to draw a rectangle on the canvas (like a selection box). I'm getting some ridiculous results, but then I noticed that even just trying the code from my reference [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html), I get huge fuzzy lines and don't know why.

it's hosted at [dylanstestserver.com/drawcss](http://dylanstestserver.com/drawcss). the javascript is inline so you can check it out. I am using jQuery to simplify getting the mouse coordinates.

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: I was also getting thick and blurry output , i was setting width and height into % or vw or vh. By setting direct px to width and height worked in my case.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For some reason, your canvas is stretched. Because you have its css property `width` set to `100%`, it is stretching it from some sort of native size. It's the difference between using the css `width` property and the `width` attribute on the `<canvas>` tag. You might want to try using a bit of javascript to make it fill the viewport ([see jQuery .width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
    canvas.width(($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //...
```

Comment: This comment really helped me, but there are a couple errors. This is the version of the code that worked for me. Since you used getElementById there is no .width() or height() function.

`var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');`
`canvas.width = parent.width();`
`canvas.height = parent.height();`

Answer (score 66):

The blurry problem will happen if you use css to set the canvas height and width instead of setting height and width in the canvas element.

```
<style>
  canvas { height: 800px; width: 1200px; }      WRONG WAY -- BLURRY LINES
</style>

<canvas height="800" width="1200"></canvas>     RIGHT WAY -- SHARP LINES
```

Answer (score 13):

The way I do it is to set the canvas element to a width and height in the css, and then set the canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth and canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight

```
var canvas =  document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: This is a good option because it lets you set the size in CSS, where it naturally belongs, IMO.

Comment: And where there are flexible ways to specify such as vw and vh.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't indicated canvas size in pixels, so it is scaled up. It is 300x150 here. Try setting the width, height

Answer (score 4):

On retina displays you also need to scale (in addition to the accepted answer):

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.scale(2,2);
```

Comment: This will increase the dimensions of the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

The css sizing issue mentioned in these comments is correct, but another more subtle thing that can cause blurred lines is forgetting to call make a call to `context.beginPath()` before drawing a line.  Without calling this, you will still get a line, but it won't be smoothed which makes the line looks like a series of steps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason mine was blurry was that there was a slight discrepancy between the inline width and the CSS width.

I have both inline width/height parameters AND css width/height assigned to my canvas, because I need to keep its physical dimensions static, while increasing its inline dimensions for retina screens.

Check yours are the same if you have a situation like mine.