# How to fix text blurring in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var text = new fabric.Text('Some text', {
  left: 100,
  top: 100
});
canvas.add(text);

$('#canvas-wrapper').mousewheel(function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1);
  } else {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1xv4vp8e/

Note how text blurs when you zoom the canvas (just use your mouse wheel and you'll notice it).

Is there any way to fix it so the text won't have that blurry effect?

Comment: Can't repro, neither on FF nor chrome on osx.

Comment: The text should not blur anymore than the standard canvas text. Fonts are vector based images. Please provide an image of the blured text so we can see the problem as the fiddle shows normal canvas behaviour.

Comment: @Blindman67 Here you go -- http://i.imgur.com/YHLfsbx.png

Comment: @Kaiido I've just tested it in Chrome, see the previous comment

Comment: @Kaiido Firefox too

Comment: Looks like you might have a Retina (hi res) display. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39951701/3877726 for info. If increasing the canvas resolution still leaves you unsatified with the canvas text quality http://stackoverflow.com/a/40074278/3877726 may help, but you will have to do your text rendering outside of Fabric

Comment: @Blindman67 By the way, are all Fabric.js fonts / text vector-based?

Comment: @Blindman67 Also, I see the same problem on non-Mac computer

Comment: fabric is retina enabled. Also i cannot reproduce.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Are you totally sure? Because I've repro this problem on Windows and Mac OS with Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: i cannot reproduce it. I have crisp text on macos chrome. when zooming in and out on that fiddle. Sure that there is no browser zoom active or maybe something else related to native resolution of monitor?

Comment: @FrozenHeart All fonts are vector based.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi fabric can not be "Retina" aware as there is no consistent way for javascript to know what the zoom level is. See the first link I gave to how to ensure (for FF, Chrome current) a 1-1 pixel canvas on hi res (also called retina if you are apple users) displays

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi That kinda strange. What resolution do you have?

Comment: So ok @Blindman67 fabric is devicePixelRatio aware, that is the best thing we can do to support retina nowadays. When they will separate screen tech spec and browser zoom in 2 separate properties then situation will improve. As of now for people that do not play with browser zoom that much, or that they do after loading the page, we can say that fabric is retina aware.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi did you try to zoom in both directions?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi I wonder what's this (http://fabricjs.com/test/svg_export/text.html) example is about. It looks like we have blurry text on the left there, and normal one on the right side. How can I achieve that?