# Canvas circle looks blurry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

This is an update to some outdated or different questions like:

- [Canvas drawings, like lines, are blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696631/canvas-drawings-like-lines-are-blurry)
- [How do I fix blurry shape edges in HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588501/how-do-i-fix-blurry-shape-edges-in-html5-canvas)

I'd like to draw a line and at the end of this line there should some kind of a circle to generate a rounded line.

Because the round-lineend should be just at one side of the line I didn't use the **line-cap property**.

Using this code below on my computer works fine but testing this code with my iPhone... The line looks -lets say OK- to tbh the circle looks just like crap: `Super blurry!`

[image: img]

```js
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 100, 0.001, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.strokeStyle = "green"
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 25%;display: table; align-self: center; width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

I couldn't find an working answer so far. But I would be super happy if somebody could fix my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

Your iPhone does not have the same *device pixel ratio* as your PC. The canvas will not render at the same resolution as it is displayed, and then can appear blurry.

You have to set a css size to your canvas, then, set this size times `window.devicePixelRatio` as the size of the canvas. Finally scale your canvas coordinate system by a factor `window.devicePixelRatio` to have a pixel perfect rendering.

(this article can help for further explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio)

> A canvas can appear too blurry on retina screens.  Use
>   window.devicePixelRatio to determine how much extra pixel density
>   should be added to allow for a sharper image.
>
> ```
> var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
> var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
>
> // Set display size (css pixels).
> var size = 200;
> canvas.style.width = size + "px";
> canvas.style.height = size + "px";
>
> // Set actual size in memory (scaled to account for extra pixel density).
> var scale = window.devicePixelRatio; // <--- Change to 1 on retina screens to see blurry canvas.
> canvas.width = size * scale;
> canvas.height = size * scale;
>
> // Normalize coordinate system to use css pixels.
> ctx.scale(scale, scale);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```js
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; margin-left: 25%;display: table; align-self: center; width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Not different at all!