How to get rid of antialiasing on generated canvas image?
I'm working on a project that I need to place an initials on top of another image, it works, but there a problem.


function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}


function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'; // Avoid CORS issues if needed
    img.onload = () => {
      resolve(img);
    };
    img.onerror = (err) => {
      console.error('Error loading image', err);
      reject(err);
    };
    img.src = url;
  });
}

async function createInitialsTextureWithImage(size = 2048, initials, imageUrl, color = [0, 0, 0]) {
  const textOffsetY = -64; 
  const textSize = 250; 

  try {
    await document.fonts.load(`normal ${textSize}px 'VCR OSD Mono'`);

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = size * 2; 
    canvas.height = size * 2; 
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const backgroundImage = await loadImage(imageUrl);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size * 2, size * 2);
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, size * 2, size * 2); 

    ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${color[0]}, ${color[1]}, ${color[2]})`; 
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.font = `${textSize * 2}px 'VCR OSD Mono'`; 
    ctx.fillText(initials, (size * 2) / 2, (size * 2) / 2 + textOffsetY * 2);

    const downscaledCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    downscaledCanvas.width = size;
    downscaledCanvas.height = size;
    const downscaledCtx = downscaledCanvas.getContext('2d');
    downscaledCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    downscaledCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, size, size);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      downscaledCanvas.toBlob((blob) => {
        const file = new File([blob], 'initials.png', {
          type: 'image/png'
        });
        resolve(file); // Resolve with the file
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error in createInitialsTextureWithImage:', err);
    throw err;
  }
}

function displayGeneratedImage(file) {
  const imgElement = document.getElementById('generatedImage');
  const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  downloadURI(imageURL, 'test.png'); // use to downloa it to local
  imgElement.src = imageURL;
}

document.getElementById('generateButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    const initials = 'NM';
    //const imageUrl = 'https://i.imgur.com/Gtwc8mZ.png'; 
    const imageUrl = 'https://i.imgur.com/V7K11Px.png';  
    const file = await createInitialsTextureWithImage(2048, initials, imageUrl, [0, 0, 0]);
    displayGeneratedImage(file);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating image:', error);
  }
});
<link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/vcr-osd-mono" rel="stylesheet">

<button id="generateButton">Generate</button>
<br><br>
<img id="generatedImage" alt="Generated Initials Texture" style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000;">



Problem is that, generated image has some antialiasing added to it and letters contain some grey colours.
Is it possible to get rid of this antialiasing?
I have tried:

scaling canvas,
setting imageSmoothingEnabled to false

but none of them helped.
Update 1:
I'm using this function for another part of the project by:
combinedTextureUrl = await createInitialsTextureWithImage(2048, initials, textureLookup);
downloadURI(combinedTextureUrl, 'test.png');

which happens because as seen in generated image it is like:

Update 2:
For some reason, downloadURI does not trigger on StackOverflow, thus I have created this fiddle which downloads the result image to local which generates the result with antialiased text.

On my screen the text looks clear without any aliasing. This is using latest Chrome on Windows. Can you provide an example image of the problem you encounter

Thank you for your response, I have updated the question.

@mrconcerned what does entering devicePixelRatio in the console return for you? Non-integer values would likely mean you should look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588501/how-do-i-fix-blurry-shape-edges-in-html5-canvas

@myf I am getting the result of 2 with window.devicePixelRatio.

I tested your Fiddle, and yes, I see the gray fringes. Now I also see them when I execute you code snippet. I went back to the original code in your question, and I think there the fringe was somewhat hidden by the pattern in the background, but when I look closely, it is there. I deleted my comments because they don't fit the question very well anymore. You can do the same with your responses. Fonts being anti-aliased is normal, of course. You could prevent it by reducing the colors to black and white.

Thank you. Could you please share it as an answer if that method solves the issue?

I can't at the moment for 2 reasons: 1. I don't actually know if this will solve your problem. It was more a hint than a solution. 2. There might still be a better solution. However, if you use my tip and think it's a good solution to your question, you can answer your own question, sharing with the community what you've found out.

I will check it later, thank you. Interestingly, question got downvoted, wonder why.

I have managed to find the solution to the problem.
I'm always having an image with 2-3 colours and I know that the color of the initials will be always black, thus I can set a loop to check every pixel and replace it with either black or white.
    const imageData = rotatedCtx.getImageData(0, 0, size, size);
    const data = imageData.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        const r = data[i];
        const g = data[i + 1];
        const b = data[i + 2];

        const grayscale = 0.3 * r + 0.59 * g + 0.11 * b;

        const newColor = grayscale < 128 ? 0 : 255;
        data[i] = data[i + 1] = data[i + 2] = newColor;
    }

    rotatedCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

with this method, it replaces the colours of grey edges with black colour.
Result:

It contains some edges, but can live with it.
