# drawImage() rendering blurry images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

[image: unzoomed]

[image: zoomed]

I have read 5+ other questions on this and they are all different from mine, because I am drawing more than one image, and because I set the width and height of my canvas in my html and not my css.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

This is how I am drawing my images (I am making a chess game)

```
function piece(color, piece, square, pieceId){
    this.dragging=false;
    this.color=color;
    this.piece=piece;
    this.square=square;
    this.moveCount=0;
    this.pieceId = pieceId;
    this.captured = false;
    this.firstMove;
    this.xCoord=square.x+(spaceWidth/2-8);
    this.yCoord=square.y+(spaceHeight/2-8);
    this.drawPiece = function(){
        if (this.color == 'w') {
            // need to get rid of these magic numbers don't really know what i am doing
            if (this.piece == 'p') {
                loadImage("img/whitepawn.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);
            } else if (this.piece == 'b') {
                loadImage("img/whitebishop.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);             } else if (this.piece == 'kn') {
                loadImage("img/whiteknight.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);             } else if (this.piece == 'r') {
                loadImage("img/whiterook.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);
            } else if (this.piece == 'k') {
                loadImage("img/whiteking.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);
            } else if (this.piece == 'q') {
                loadImage("img/whitequeen.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);              }
        } else if (this.color == 'b') { // black piece
            // need to get rid of these magic numbers don't really know what i am doing
            if (this.piece == 'p') {
                loadImage("img/blackpawn.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);
            } else if (this.piece == 'b') {
                loadImage("img/blackbishop.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);             } else if (this.piece == 'kn') {
                loadImage("img/blackknight.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);             } else if (this.piece == 'r') {
                loadImage("img/blackrook.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);
            } else if (this.piece == 'k') {
                loadImage("img/blackking.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);
            } else if (this.piece == 'q') {
                loadImage("img/blackqueen.png", this.xCoord-4, this.yCoord-3);              }
        } else {
            ;
        }
    }
}

function loadImage( src, x, y) {
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = src;
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, 25, 25);
    };
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have been trying to figure this out all day, and could use some help.

Comment: Could you provide an [mcve] with e.g only one of these images ? (you can upload it on stackoverflow's imgur account). On which browser do you experience this issue (some still have a prefixed version of imageSmoothingEnabled.

Comment: Is there a way to get the images files img/*.png that are to be displayed, so that I can test this on my laptop ?

Comment: Yes, let me try to figure out how to do the imgur thing, and also I am using chrome. Just tried in safari and it still looks bad though

Comment: First thing that occurs to me is, are the positions whole integers? I believe the canvas will try to render sub-pixel if positions and/or sizes are not whole ints.

Comment: It looks like I can only upload them to the post one at a time. All of the images are here https://github.com/Kyle628/Wizard_Chess/tree/pawns-luke-branch/img

Comment: oh no they are not whole integers, let me try taking the floor or ceiling or something!

Comment: Cool lemme know if that works :)

Comment: Dangit, I thought that was going to work for sure. No luck =/

Comment: @KyleO'Connor Do you have a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: @Clonkex just edited post to include screenshot

Comment: Well your Chrome is zoomed. Try unzooming your Chrome.

Comment: I just zoomed in to emphasize the blurriness

Comment: I downloaded your game from your github and I'm seeing quite sharp-edged images, unless I zoom in. Can you give us another screenshot without the zoom plsplspls? Also, I'm on Windows. Maybe it's a weird thing with Chrome on Mac? Not that that really helps you, but it might be useful to know.

Comment: I do have an idea but I want to see what you're seeing first.

Comment: Okay thank you for taking time to help me! I uploaded an unzoomed screenshot. I am on a mac, and I saw on another post people were talking about retina displays...hmm

Comment: That is a retina display (if the unzoomed image is not scaled by you) you need to double the canvas size or use the CSS rule "image-rendering: pixelated;" to stop the blurring due to canvas bilinear filtering. Some related answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/41776757/3877726 http://stackoverflow.com/a/39951701/3877726

Comment: @Blindman wow that worked! Had to double the size of the canvas and add ctx.scale(2,2).....if you want to post an answer I will mark it accepted answer

Comment: Awesome, glad you got your answer! For the record, my idea was going to be to try making the chess piece images much smaller, preferably the exact size they will be when you draw them to the canvas. I was wondering if maybe Chrome was deciding to filter the images on Mac only... either way they may look better if they're not being resized from 1000px down to 25px :P

Comment: @KyleO'Connor if you want to give an upvote just give to one of the links provided if they helped at all, else all good that you got your problem fixed. Have fun writing the chess game :)

Comment: @Blindman67 Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @Clonkex Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably comes from the interpolation that the browser does when you draw your images.

Unfortunately there is no standart way of undoing this.

Here is a question with some maybe helpful clues:
[Disable Interpolation when Scaling a <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas)

An easier, uglier fix might be to use higher resolution imagaes (scale them up in your favourite image processing tool and choose closest as the interpolation setting).