# How to scale canvas on mobile and desktop devices

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

After some research and a lot trial and error I wrote following bar chart:

```
function extractResults(container) {
    var results = [];
    for (result of container.children) {
        var parts = result.innerText.split("-")
        results.push(parseInt(parts[1].trim().split(" ")[0]));
    }
    return results
}
var results = extractResults($("#results"));
var canvas = $("#chart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var margin = canvas.width * 0.005;
var bWidth = (canvas.width - (margin * results.length)) / results.length;
var max = Math.max.apply( Math, results );
var yScale = canvas.height / max;
var currX = margin;
ctx.font = "20px Arial"
for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
{
    var bHeight = yScale * results[i];
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(currX, canvas.height - bHeight, bWidth, bHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText(i + 1, currX + bWidth / 2, canvas.height - canvas.height * 0.05, bWidth / 2);
    currX += bWidth + margin;
}
```

Everything is computed based on the canvas height and width, but how should I set them? What value would look good on mobile and desktop devices. I do not use any framework and the html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Results - Is this site great? - easypolls</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/polls/css/polls.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2><a href="/">easypolls</a></h2><hr />

    <h3>Is this site great?</h3>
    <p>04-14-2017 8:05 p.m. (UTC)</p>
    <canvas id="chart"><p>Graphs are not supported by this browser.</p></canvas>
    <ul id="results">

            <li>1.Yes. - 3 votes</li>

            <li>2.No. - 0 votes</li>

            <li>3.It looks awful! - 1 vote</li>

    </ul>

    <p><label>Share:<input type="text" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/results/" readonly /></label></p>
    <p><label>Embed:<input type="text" value="<iframe src=&quot;http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/results/&quot;></iframe>" readonly /></label></p>


    <script src="/static/js/shortcuts.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/polls/js/results.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inner width & height

The browser provides information regarding the browser window size with [innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth), [innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight), [outerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth), [outerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerHeight), [screenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX), and [screenY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenY)

For example: To set the canvas resolution to match the browser's page.

```
canvas.width  = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
```

Note : All pixel values are CSS pixels which may not be actual physical pixels, such as when the client has zoomed the page, or if the display is a retina or very high res display. This can result in lower quality canvas images due to bilinear filtering. There is no standard way of detecting retina or zoomed  so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39951701/3877726) gives a simple solution if this is a problem and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776757/3877726) gives a more detailed method of detecting retina / high res displays.

#### Window.screen

You can also use [the screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) object to get information about the device's screen.