# image rendering blurry when using html to canvas, using JavaScript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I am trying ot convert html elements to image using the following code, but text int eh image getting an blurry text. any one can help me on this., here is the code

```
    setTimeout( function(){
        //get the div content
        div_content = document.querySelector("#container_inc");
        html2canvas(div_content).then(function(canvas) {
            //change the canvas to jpeg image
            data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/mailsend/save_jpg', {data: data}, function(res)
        {});
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });
    }  , 2000 );

    $email_bodymsg = '';
    $imgname = $this->session->userdata("sess_imgname");
    echo $email_bodymsg = '<div><img src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/sample/user-image/'.$imgname.'.jpg" ></div>';



public function save_jpg()
    {
        $random ='Main-Data-Dashboard'.rand(100, 1000);
        $this->session->set_userdata("sess_imgname", $random);
        $savefile = file_put_contents("assets/user-image/$random.jpg", base64_decode(explode(",", $_POST['data'])[1]));

        if($savefile){
            echo $random;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it sending blob data?

Comment: @Irfan it will create a jpeg file,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas stroke() thick and fuzzy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991113/html5-canvas-stroke-thick-and-fuzzy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the canvas's  `width` and `height`, I think maybe this cause the 'blurry',like:

```
<canvas width='1920' height='1080'></canvas>
```

canvas's default `width` and `height` is not very big, maybe you can try to set it bigger.